# JavaScript validation form integratation into one

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form with inputs

- Fist name
- Last name
- Password
- Etc

Current my validation works one by one. I would like to integrate them into one pop up box.
Example currently:
All not filled up; upon submission it would pop up First name not filled. I want it to be First name not filled, last name not filled etc

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["firstname"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("First Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["lastname"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Last Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    var status = false;
    var emailRegEx = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
    if (document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value.search(emailRegEx) == -1) {
        alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
        return false;
    }
    var status = false;
    var paswordregex = /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$/;
    if (document.forms["myForm"]["password"].value.search(paswordregex) == -1) {
        alert("Please enter a at least 8 alphanumeric characters");
        return false;
    }
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var confirmPassword = document.getElementById("confirmpassword").value;
    if (password != confirmPassword) {
        alert("Passwords do not match.");
        return false;
    }
    var checkb = document.getElementById('checkboxid');
    if (checkb.checked != true) {
        alert('Agree to privacy agreement must be checked');
    } else {
        status = true;
    }
    return status;
}
```

Comment: so, just don't `return` after a validation fail. let the function continue.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers given!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var regexEmail = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
    var regexMinThree = /^[A-Za-z0-9_ ]{3,13}$/;

    var userFirstName = $.trim($('.firstName').val());
    var userLastName = $.trim($('.lastName').val());
    var userEmail = $.trim($('.email').val());
    var userPassword = $.trim($('.password').val());

    var msg = '';

    if(!regexMinThree.test(userFirstName)) {
       msg = 'FirstName, ';
    } else {
       msg = '';
    }

    if(!regexMinThree.test(userLastName)) {
       msg = msg+'LastName, ';
    } else {
       msg = msg+'';
    }

    if(!regexEmail.test(userEmail)) {
       msg = msg+'Email, ';
    } else {
       msg = msg+'';
    }

    if(!regexMinThree.test(userPassword)) {
       msg = msg+'Password, ';
    } else {
       msg = msg+'';
    }

    if(!regexMinThree.test(userPassword) || !regexEmail.test(userEmail) || !regexMinThree.test(userLastName) || !regexMinThree.test(userFirstName)) {
       msg = msg+'not filled correctly.';
       alert(msg);
    }
}
</script>

<form class="userRegistrationForm" onsubmit="return false;" method="post">
<input type="text" class="firstName" placeholder ="FirstName"/>
<input type="text" class="lastName" placeholder ="LastName"/>
<input type="email" class="email" placeholder ="Email"/>
<input type="password" class="password" placeholder ="Password"/>
<button type="submit" onclick="validateForm()" class="userRegistration">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a flag called error and a string called errorMessage, then in each if statement, if there is an error, make error = true and append error message.

Then when submitted, if error == true, alert errorMessage

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `<ul>` in your html form where you want to show errors

**Example**

```
<ul class="errorContainer"></ul>
```

Then **JS**

```
function validateForm() {
    var errors = "";
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["firstname"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
       errors +="<li>First Name must be filled out</li>";

    }
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["lastname"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
         errors +="<li>Last Name must be filled out</li>";

    }
    var status = false;
    var emailRegEx = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
    if (document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value.search(emailRegEx) == -1) {
         errors +="<li>Please enter a valid email address.</li>";

    }
    var status = false;
    var paswordregex = /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$/;
    if (document.forms["myForm"]["password"].value.search(paswordregex) == -1) {
         errors +="<li>Please enter a at least 8 alphanumeric characters</li>";

    }
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var confirmPassword = document.getElementById("confirmpassword").value;
    if (password != confirmPassword) {
         errors +="<li>Passwords do not match.</li>";

    }
    var checkb = document.getElementById('checkboxid');
    if (checkb.checked != true) {
         errors +="<li>Agree to privacy agreement must be checked</li>";
    }

    if(errors!="")
    {
       $(".errorContainer").html(errors);
       return false;
    } else {
        status = true;
        return status;
    }

}
```